# Android Firebase pass data iterate map

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

I want to pass data from first activity to second activity. But when I want to read the data in the second activity response is null. How can I solve this problem?

Firebase Node

```
Pro_:
     Basket:
        ID_1:
           cat: “Tech”
           info:”iOS” 
           orderid:”Ref_1” 
        ID_2:
           cat: “Tech”
           info:”Android” 
           orderid:”Ref_2” 
     name:”Mike”
```

My struct

```
public class Name_Struct implements Serializable {
   private String name;
   private Map<String, Object> basket;
  public String getName() {
       return name;
   }
   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }
   @PropertyName("Basket")
   public Map<String, Object> getBasket() {
       return basket;
   }
   public void setBasket(Map<String, Object> basket) {
       this.basket = basket;
   }
}
```

First Activity

```
private void retrieve_data(){
    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child(“Pro_”);
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            mName.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot snp : snapshot.getChildren()){
                Name_Struct names = snp.getValue(Name_Struct.class);
                    mName.add(names);
                
            }
            mName_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        }
    });
}
```

EDIT_1 First Adapter

```
final Name_Struct newModel = Name_Struct(position);

        Bundle bundle1=new Bundle();
        bundle1.putSerializable("basket", (Serializable) newModel.getBasket());
        intent.putExtras(bundle1);
```

EDIT_1 Second Activity

```
Map <String, Object> map1 = (Map)bundle.getSerializable("basket");
   Detail_Struct detail = new Detail_Struct(
          map1.get("cat"),map1.get("info"),map1.get("orderid"));
    mDetail_Struct.add(detail);

for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map1.entrySet()) {
    Log.d("Map_array:"+ map1);
```

> Map_array:{ID_1={cat=Tech, info=iOS, orderid=Ref_1}, D_2={cat=Tech,
> info=Android, orderid=Ref_2}}

```
        Log.d("Map_value:"+ entry.getValue());
```

> Map_value:{cat=Tech, info=iOS, orderid=Ref_1} Map_value:{cat=Tech,
> info=Android, orderid=Ref_2}

```
        Log.d("Map_object:"+ map1.get("orderid"));
```

null line???

> Map_object:null Map_object:null

```
    }
```

EDIT_1 Detail Struct

```
public class Detail_Struct {
    private String cat;
    private String info;
    private String orderid;

public String getCat() {
    return cat;
}
public void setCat(String cat) {
    this.cat = cat;
}
public String getInfo() {
    return info;
}
public void setInfo(String info) {
    this.info = info;
}
public String getOrderid() {
    return orderid;
}
public void setOrderid(String orderid) {
    this.orderid = orderid;
}
```

Comment: Where in your code are you adding that Map to the Bundle object?

Comment: I edited question.I'm trying add to Detail _Struct in second activity.

Comment: Does `newModel.getBasket()` return what you need?

Comment: Yes it does however, I'm not parsing the detail(Detail_Struct) in second activity

Comment: Do you have any idea this problem Alex?

Comment: Since it returns what you need, most likely it's a matter of how you send to the second activity, right?

Comment: Yes, actually ı observe in second activity as array. But ı can not parsing array  (in second activity) so ı cannot send to second adapter(Log.d("Map_object:"+ map1.get("orderid") //null);)